# NodeJS: Execute stored procedure and get OUT Parameter

Tags: node.js, stored-procedures

I want to call a stored procedure and get the return value in node.
I'm able to do it 2 calls. 1 for calling procedure and the other for returning value.

I'm using  **mysql** module

```
sqlcon.query("call CountOrderByStatus('done',@total);", function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(rows);
                }
                else{
                    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
                    console.error(err)
                }
            });
            sqlcon.query("select @total;", function(err, rows, fields) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(rows);

                }
                else{
                    console.log('Error while performing Query.');
                    console.error(err)
                }
            });
        });
```

Is there any way to get it it one call?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in node-mysql

```js
sqlcon.query('SELECT 1; SELECT 2', function(err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // `results` is an array with one element for every statement in the query:
  console.log(results[0]); // [{1: 1}]
  console.log(results[1]); // [{2: 2}]
});
```

Comment: That is throwing error.. Whenever we use 2 queries in single query

Comment: You need to use {multipleStatements: true} while creating connection. Something like this: 
```var sqlcon = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});```